# Laravel apply method concatenation conditionally

Tags: laravel, methods, concatenation, conditional-statements

By Looking at this code:

```
if($status == 'processed'){
    DB::connection('mydb')
                            ->table('logs')
                            ->where('id', $id)
                            ->update(array('status' => $status));
}else{
   DB::connection('mydb')
                            ->table('logs')
                            ->where('id', $id)
                            ->where('id2', $id2)
                            ->update(array('status' => $status));
}
```

The semantic of the code doesn't make much sense since it's an extract from a bigger file. Any way I'm focusing on how to concatenate more methods after a given condition
like above

```
if(A)
    DB->method1()->method2()
else  
    DB->method1()->method3()->method2()
```

Any idea on how to write this in a more elegant way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `where` clause to the same query object:

```php
$query = DB::connection('mydb')->table('logs')->where('id', $id);

if ($status != 'processed') {
    $query->where('id2', $id2);
}

$query->update(['status' => $status]);
```

Comment: So basically statement is fired only when invoking update, in this case, Before I can set up all the builds... Thanks